# <Source> tag seems not working in <picture> tag

Tags: html

I try to use webp to save the loading time. But the picture tag only read the last one img tag.

```html
<picture>
  <source srcset="img/index-bg.webp" type="image/webp">
  <img srcset="img/index-bg.png" alt="test">
</picture>
```

I checked my src and it all correct. I use google developer and I can see the webp picture.It seems only not working in picture tag.

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The missed part is the **media attribute**, which is required if you want to render conditionally based on screen width.
Follow this syntax:

```
<picture>
    <source srcset="/media/cc0-images/surfer-240-200.jpg"
            media="(min-width: 800px)">
    <img src="/media/cc0-images/painted-hand-298-332.jpg" alt="" />
</picture>
```

Do check this link: [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/picture][1]